# space issue in bearer token in react js

Tags: reactjs, token

I m using Bearer token in my reactjs project and getting token form localstorage but space not coming properly between Bearer and Token

**Code**

```
const TOKEN = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN');
Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${TOKEN}`;
```

**Result**

```
Authorization: BearerN1ZuxkpgOlOfMGK3hrsl9N4UveoX-67hDH6jRDc5DgEA5yZpDxdyorIMCAeDV5vmHndKsapoYEqiXtoEPzT4vk6FQNOiQQRGdybZ-kfayEF2UaN7IJF0ui1nC8-hfpuzQddzBCg9PoskBzUJCc5ajYzp9VSNmo-nGtigEpyiqw7A5HDxi8GGytvkCGsM0-feW3FEy05VSKzkSu8pxTHR_Ism_uTTIxjrhiOEzMka5-qbhSQyTV1b5B_n_f_gsYX2
```

Comment: Your code should work. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I agree this should work. Was this copy/pasted from somewhere? Maybe the space isn’t actually a space? Have you tried just retyping the template string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code formatter like `prettier` must be removing the space. In meantime you could use this line

```
Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = 'Bearer'+' '+TOKEN;
```

Answer (score 0):

That's the correct way to define the header.

```
const TOKEN = localStorage.getItem('TOKEN');
Axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${TOKEN}`;
```